# Completely erasing three.js scene

Tags: angularjs, three.js

I have an application with three.js and angularjs. My main view is three scene but sometimes the user would like to change the view (look at some other html pages). The problem is when the user navigates back to three view, angular controller gets reinitiated and the three scene gets re-made thus webgl crashes.

I've tried to stop calling for animation frames and null everything related to three but this does not seem to help. Any ideas how to make view changing work properly?

Comment: angular will re-render the dom when $scope changes, or put that canvas dom outside angular scope.

Comment: Does not sound like a good solution. Then I'd have to manage the canvas separately so it would not be visible on top of other pages.